# viewing Tiff attachments in Gmail

Tags: gmail, attachments

I'm running the latest Gmail app 4.3.1 on a Galaxy Note 2. There seems to be a bug when receiving email containing tiff attachment (fax documents in my case). 
The tiff images are shown as preview within gmail app. When clicking on the preview it does not switch into some viewer, there's a endless progress indicator.

Is there a workaround or (even better) a solution for this?

Comment: How big are the files? TIFFs can be rather large, and if you're not on WiFi it wouldn't surprise me at all if it takes too long to download.

Comment: I sent myself a 7.4 MB `.tif` file (a screen shot) and it's been "downloading" for at least 4 minutes now. I'm not hopeful that it's going to work.

Comment: [Gmail attachment download](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.poofinc.gmailattach) might work for you.

Comment: Failing that, some combination of auto-forwarding and [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) might help.